# How to add a Page Number Reference to a table cell in a MS Word Footer

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml

I have searched the internet trying to find an answer to this problem. I am creating a program that will automatically add a footer to word documents that are in a folder. The footer contains a table that has 2 rows and 3 columns. Everything is working except that the footer needs a page number reference in one of the cells.
This is the part of my code now:

```
using Word=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

Word.Table table = section.Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterEvenPages].Range.Tables.Add(section.Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterEvenPages].Range,2,3);
table.Range.Font.Size=8;
table.Range.Font.Name="Arial";
table.Cell(2,2).Range.Text="01 00 00 - "/*This is where the page number reference needs to be*/;
```

I have tried:

```
section.Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterEvenPages].PageNumbers.Add();
```

and

```
table.Cell(2,2).Range.Fields.Add(table.Cell(2,2).Range,Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage);
```

and neither would work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I created a round-a-bout way of adding the page number, so if anyone has a better answer, please feel free to add on.

```
Word.Range rng=table.Cell(2,2).Range;
rng.End=rng.End-1;
rng.Start=rng.End;
rng.Select();
app.Selection.Range.Fields.Add(app.Selection.Range,Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage,oMissing,oMissing);
```